# Leaving my company - Holiday entitlement pay

Tags: communication, human-resources, united-kingdom, resignation, law

Over the past 4 weeks I have been working out my notice. I dont know if this is standard in every country (Im from the uk) but tomorrow is my last day and Im having some trouble with sorting out the pay I am owed concerning the remaining holiday.

In the contract, to work out the remaining holiday the equation is [Holiday days entitled to] / 12 (months) x [how many months youve worked].

28 / 12 x 2 = 4.666... lets say we round this down to 4.5 days holiday.

The HR exect says that I am only entitled too full days. So its only 4.

I am arguing I am fully entitled to that 0.5 day.

I was asked not to take them off during my notice period and told id be paid for them.

Am I fully entitled to receive payment for that half day? And if so can I send him anything that backs up my point?

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this calculator](https://www.gov.uk/calculate-your-holiday-entitlement)?

Comment: Thanks mikeazo, I know that 4.5 is my holiday left I am entitled too as I worked it out from the above details in my contract. I just wanted to know if the employer is entitiled to pay for half days, are are they legally allowed to round down?

Comment: My employer has replied that employers have the right to decide whether they round up or down holiday. But surely not when the days owed is 4.66 - Its closer to 5. I dont expect them to round up. But i dont expect them to round down to a full day

Comment: http://www.grammar.cl/Notes/Two_Too_To.htm

Comment: @Jason - It is employees like you who quibble over a couple dollars that explains the reason that employers have so many ridiculous rules. Especially regarding vacation and sick time. You can bet the company will be writing a new policy to cover your exact situation. And this policy will certainly come at the expense of employees in totally unforseen ways.

Comment: @Dunk, in this case it is the government that wrote the rules. Company policy cannot be in violation of federal law.

Comment: @mikeazo - Perhaps, but it is very common that one reads the rules and they are very clear until you go read a different set of rules that contradicts the rules. My point is that some things are worth fighting for, other times what's the point? While the OP may "win" this particular argument, it is relatively meaningless situations like this that end up causing sometimes draconian policy changes by companies that once let common sense and simple coordination between managers and employees set the boundaries.

Comment: @Dunk - As mikeazo said, the Government wrote these rules and he was violating them. And regarding "quibble over a couple dollars" - The amount in question was a lot more than "a couple of dollars". And no matter the amount, I am fully entitled to ask for the money I am owed. The company wont be writing a new policy, they will be following the one already put in place. And the issue wasnt that I wanted the money, I either wanted the money or the time off. The issue was originally he was prohibiting both. There is no issue to expect to receive what you are entitled too. No harm to employees.

Comment: Also regarding this as off topic - Its a small company so he was HR - The argument was with the head of HR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the calculator that @mikeazo provided:

> The employer:
>
> - can include bank and public holidays as part of the statutory entitlement
> - **must not round down the holiday entitlement, but may round it up**
> - must provide holiday pay during the statutory leave
> - can provide more paid holiday - this will be in the employment contract and is called ‘contractual leave entitlement’

I would suggest talking to your citizens council to confirm where in the labor act this is specified and then bring it up with HR.

Comment: I did see that, I read http://www.nidirect.gov.uk/taking-your-holiday - "They cannot be rounded down, but do not need to be rounded up to the nearest full day. An employer can, however, choose to do so if they wish."

Comment: @JsonsJSON, sounds like you have enough information and evidence to start asking the questions at HR. Hope this all works out in your favor.

Comment: Thanks Mikeazo,  They told me that he has the right to choose whether he rounds down or up my day. I sent them - http://www.acas.org.uk/media/pdf/7/o/Holidays-and-holiday-pay.pdf & http://www.nidirect.gov.uk/taking-your-holiday to back up my point that an employer cannot round down a day, only round up a day or leave it at what is owed - in my case a half day

Comment: @JasonsJSON let us know how it goes. Good luck.

Comment: @mikeazo - Thanks, In the end he reviewed the policies and references I sent, and admitted he was wrong. I received my holiday. Thanks